# how to count returning zero? ms sql

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I'm having some trouble running something basic in ms sql server. I've tried several ways, some found on forums, but always gives me errors.

Imagine I have a table with hospital data from several people. I have special interest in two columns: one corresponds to the code (type number) of the town where the person lives and the other corresponds to the age group (type in text) at the time the person was hospitalized. example:

```
 .. city_code | group_age...
 ______________________________

         111  |  65 - 69
         1195 |   + 95
         203  |  70 - 74
         1176 |  85 - 89
         203  |  70 - 74
```

What I want is to create a new table that tells me how many people in each city and each age group exist in the database:

```
 ...city_code | 65 - 69 | 70_74 | 75 - 79 | 80 - 84 | 85 - 89 | 90 - 94 | +95
      111     |    1    |   0   |    0    |    0    |    0    |    0    |  0
      203     |    0    |   2   |    0    |    0    |    0    |    0    |  0
     1176     |    0    |   0   |    0    |    0    |    1    |    0    |  0
     1195     |    0    |   0   |    0    |    0    |    0    |    0    |  1
```

I can create this table EXCEPT when the result is zero. It does not assume any value, which would mean I have to check one by one which is zero, which would be impossible given the amount of data that I'm working with.

Among the ways that I tried, the more I saw was:

```
select city_code, sum(case when age_group = '65-69' then 1 else 0 end) as '65-69',
                  sum(case when age_group= '+95' then 1 else 0 end) as '+95' 
from table1;
```

This gives me a syntax error constantly. I need help having an idea how to do it the fastest way possible through consultation structures in ms sql server.

Thank you and I hope you understood my problem!

Comment: Looks like your main issue is your using the field name age_group in your query when your table has the field name as group_age.

Comment: Why the MS Access tag?

Comment: David, that is just an example. I did not notice that error, sorry. You can see the real database, or part of it at least, in another comment I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a group by clause at the end in order to have the sums be grouped by each city_code:

```
from table1
group by city_code
```

You may also need to put your aliased column names in brackets, not single quotes.  So

```
as [65-69]
```

instead of

```
as '65-69'
```

Comment: Yes, I had already done that, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you post the error that you are getting rather than just saying its a syntax error?

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'sum(case when age_group = '65-69' then 1 else 0 end) as '65-69', sum(case when age_group= '+95' then 1 else 0 end)'

Comment: Try putting your table name in square brackets (so [65-69] for example)

Comment: Check my latest edit, I mentioned the wrong column to put brackets around prior.

Comment: I was able to get it running with the quotes around the field name after the AS.  The place it looks like the problem is at is when you get the age group, you are using the age_group name when the field in the table is group_age.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the static column names in your example:

```
SELECT
    city_code,
    [65 - 69] = SUM(CASE group_age WHEN '65 - 69' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [70 - 74] = SUM(CASE group_age WHEN '70 - 74' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [75 - 79] = SUM(CASE group_age WHEN '75 - 79' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [80 - 84] = SUM(CASE group_age WHEN '80 - 84' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [85 - 89] = SUM(CASE group_age WHEN '85 - 89' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [90 - 94] = SUM(CASE group_age WHEN '90 - 94' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    [+ 95] = SUM(CASE group_Age WHEN '+ 95' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table1
GROUP BY city_code
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae39b/1)

For a more dynamic approach that will pick up age groups as they are added:

```
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Columns = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(group_age)
                      FROM table1
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
                     1, 1, '');
SET @Query = 'SELECT city_code, ' + @Columns + ' ' +
             'FROM (SELECT city_code, group_age ' +
                   'FROM table1) t '+
             'PIVOT ' +
             '(COUNT(group_age) FOR group_age IN (' + @Columns + ')) p';
EXECUTE(@Query);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae39b/5)

Comment: Thanks, but I just try and still give the same error as always:Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[65 - 69] = SUM(CASE grupo_etário WHEN '65 - 69' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'

Comment: Something is getting lost in translation. Please provide the _exact_ table structure and query in use.

Comment: Try removing the spaces in the names, like '65-69' instead of '65 - 69'.  Access doesn't play nicely with spaces in column names.

Comment: @Andrew No problem with columns containing spaces in Access (other than database design smell) as long as they're [surrounded with backticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711819%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The question mentions SQL Server, not sure why Access is tagged.

Comment: Please check my new answer. You can see part of my database there!

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Ok, so first I am talking about the microsoft access sql server. I should have written it all and not just the initials. Sorry about that.

In the picture you can see as part of my database looks like. The columns that I'm talking  are "grupo_etário" (group_age) and "cod_mun" (city_code).

Beargle, I tried your second suggestion and gave a new error: Invalid SQL statement; expected 'Delete', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT' or 'UPDATE'.

Regarding to spaces, I have also thought about it but I've read the explanation of beargle and I think therefore that it is not a problem.